# Error using the .at operator openCV (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, runtime-error

[![Here is the image- skelt.tif(img)][1]][1]I am trying to find access the Mat element, angl (gradient angle). However when I use the .at statement, it throws an error.

I have already checked for NULL image (angl.data==NULL). This is not a NULL image.

Here is the code:

```
  Mat img = imread("skelt.tif"); // this is a binary image
  Mat grad_x(img.rows, img.cols, CV_16U);
  Mat grad_y(img.rows, img.cols, CV_16U);
  Mat angl;
  Sobel(img, grad_x, CV_32F, 1, 0, 3);// Gradient X
  Sobel(img,grad_y, CV_32F, 0, 1, 3); // Gradient Y
  phase(grad_x, grad_y, angl,true);
  cout << angl.at<float>(51, 5) << endl; // the dimensions are randomly chosen and are within the image
  cout<<angl.ptr(5)[4];
```

The error is in the places where the .at operator is used. The error is -

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)pt.y < (unsigned)
size.p[0] && (unsigned)(pt.x * DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1] *
 channels()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) &
((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file c:\opencv\build\in
clude\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 912
```

I am unable to debug this error.

Comment: so first load your image as grayscale with `imread("skelt.tif",0)` to be sure it has one channel. Then you create grad_x and grad_y as `CV_16U` but your `Sobel` output is `CV_32F`

Comment: what is the size of the skelt.tif?  img.rows, img.cols ?

Comment: @GpG The size of skelt.tif is [665 X 489]

Comment: @PSchn I am now reading the image as imread("skelt.tif",0) and I changed grad_x, grad_y to CV_32F. It still gives an error.

Comment: Can you access the other images(grad_x,grad_y)? And what type is angl? Check with `angl.type()` and lookup [here](http://ninghang.blogspot.de/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html?m=1)

Comment: I have tried the above code with custom image (400x400) and it works fine.

Comment: @PSchn Yes, I am able to access grad_x, grad_y using the same way. The type of angl is CV_32F (C1).

Comment: Does this produce expected result: Mat img = imread("skelt.tif"); cout << img.rows << img.cols << img.dims?

Comment: How did you generate your random numbers? Maybe there is the problem?!

Comment: @PSchn Initially, I tried to access all the points in the image. However, this gave an error. Now, I am just plugging in random (x,y) coordinates. I tried various (x,y) values. All of these give an error.

Comment: @GpG the size of img is [665 X 489]. However, img.rows =489, img.cols=665 and img.dims=2 . Is this right?

Comment: Can you provide your Image?

Comment: try substituting Mat img = imread("skelt.tif"); with Mat img = Mat(489,665,CV_8UC3). Is it working in this case?

Comment: @GpG I tried it. This does not help

Comment: some time ago I was experiencing a strange behavior with opencv. I think I was building my application on debug while linking release opencv libraries (or wise versa). are you linking the debug libraries. Which version of opencv are you using by the way?

Answer (score 0):

Your image `angl` is not the size or type you think it is, or is empty.

Try checking the type with `angl.type()` and size with `angl.rows angl.cols`

If there is a problem it is probably in the phase() call which we don't have, are you sure you are modifying the angl image and not a copy ?

Comment: The size of img is [665 X 489].  img.rows =489, img.cols=665 and img.dims=2 , img.type= CV_32F.

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case, you can debug into OpenCV to check the variables at that assert call which throws the error. To do that, you need to download the source of your OpenCV version and tell the debugger where the source files are located.

Once you have set up the debugging of the OpenCV source, you can simply jump into the .at call with your debugger to see which part of the assert condition fails.